# Error al ejecutar mi programa

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa como tarea de instituto.

Al ejecutar el programa me da este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Instituto1.asignarAsignatura(Instituto1.java:103)
>       at Programa.main(Programa.java:26)

Os dejo el código para que podáis ver el fallo.

Programa principal:

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instituto ins1 = new Instituto1("Instituto 1");
        //Crear Curso
        ins1.crearCurso("01", "DAM");

        //Crear Asignatura
        ins1.crearAsignatura("M2", "Base de Dades", 6, "10");
        ins1.asignarAsignatura("01", "M2"); 
    }

}
```

Instituto1:

```
public class Instituto1 implements Instituto {
    //VARIABLES
        String nombre;
        private Profesor[] profesor;
        private Alumno[] alumno;
        private Curso[] curso;
        private Asignatura[] asignatura;

        private Profesor1[] profesor1;
        private Alumno1[] alumno1;

        private int nProfesor;
        private int nAlumnos;
        private int nCursos;
        private int nAsignaturas;

    //CONSTRUCTORES
        public Instituto1(String nombre){
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.profesor = new Profesor[10]; 
            this.alumno = new Alumno[10];
            this.curso = new Curso[10];
            this.asignatura = new Asignatura[10];

            this.nProfesor = 0;
            this.nAlumnos = 0;
            this.nCursos = 0;
            this.nAsignaturas = 0;
        }

    //SETs

    //GETs

    //Operaciones
        public void crearProfesor(String nombre, String dni) {
            this.profesor[this.nProfesor] = new Profesor1(nombre,dni);

            this.nProfesor ++;

            System.out.println("Profesor Creado");
        }

        public void crearAlumno(String nombre, String dni) {
            this.alumno[this.nAlumnos] = new Alumno1(nombre,dni);

            this.nAlumnos ++;

            System.out.println("Alumno Creado");
        }

        public void crearCurso(String codigo, String nombre) {
            this.curso[this.nCursos] = new Curso(codigo, nombre);

            this.nCursos ++;

            System.out.println("Curso Creado");
        }

        public void crearAsignatura(String codigo, String nombre, int horasSemanales, String aula) {
            this.asignatura[this.nAsignaturas] = new Asignatura(codigo,nombre,horasSemanales, aula);

            this.nAsignaturas ++;

            System.out.println("Asignatura Creada");
        }

        public Profesor getProfesor(String dni){

            int i = 0;

            while(this.profesor[i].getDni().equalsIgnoreCase(dni)){ 
                i++;
            }

            System.out.print("Profesor Encontrado");

            return profesor[i];

        }

        public Alumno getAlumno(String dni) {

            int i = 0;

            while(this.alumno[i].getDni().equalsIgnoreCase(dni)){
                i++;
            }

            System.out.print("Alumno Encontrado");

            return alumno[i];

        }

        public void asignarAsignatura(String codigoCurso, String codigoAsignatura) {

            int i = 0;  
            int j = 0;

            while(this.curso[i].getCodigoCurso().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoCurso)){                
                i ++;
            }

            while(this.asignatura[j].getCodigoAsignatura().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoAsignatura)){
                j ++;
            }

            this.curso[i].asignarAsignatura(this.asignatura[j]);

            System.out.print("Asignatura Asignada");


        }

        public void asignarProfesor(String codigoAsignatura, String dni) {
            //int i = 0;
            //int j = 0;

            //while(this.asignatura[i].getCodigoAsignatura().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoAsignatura)) {
            //  i ++;
            //}

            //while(this.profesor1[j].getDni().equalsIgnoreCase(dni)) {
            //  j ++;
            //}

            //this.profesor1[j].asignarProfesor(this.asignatura[i]);

            //System.out.print("Profesor Asignado");

        }

        public void asignarAlumno(String codigoCurso, String dni) {
            //int i = 0;
            //int j = 0;

            //while(this.curso[i].getCodigoCurso().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoCurso)) {
            //  i++;
            //}

            //while(this.alumno[j].getDni().equalsIgnoreCase(dni)) {
            //  j++;
            //}

            //  this.alumno1[j].asignarAlumno(this.curso[i]);
        }

        public String informeAsignatura(String codigoAsignatura) {

            //int i = 0;

            //while(this.asignatura[i].getCodigoAsignatura().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoAsignatura)) {
            //  i++;
            //}


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;            
        }

        public String verAula(String codigoAsignatura) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public String verAulaAsignatura(String aula) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public String verAlumnosCurso(String codigoCurso) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    //toString
        public String toString(){
            String s="";

            s+= "El nombre del Instituto es: "+this.nombre;

            return s;
        }
}
```

Curso:

```
public class Curso {
    //VARIABLES
        String codigo;
        String nombre;

        Asignatura[] asignaturas;
        int contAsignaturas;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
        public Curso(String codigo, String nombre){
            this.codigo = codigo;
            this.nombre = nombre;

            this.contAsignaturas = 0;
        }

    //SETs
        public void setNombre(String nombre){
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public void setCodigoCurso(String codigo){
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }   

    //GETs
        public String getNombreCurso(){
            return this.nombre;
        }

        public String getCodigoCurso(){
            return this.codigo;
        }

    //OPERACIONES

        public void asignarAsignatura(Asignatura a){

            this.asignaturas[this.contAsignaturas] = a;

            this.contAsignaturas ++;

        }

    //toString
        public String toString(){
            String s="";

            s+= "El nombre del CURSO es: "+this.nombre;
            s+= "y el codigo es: "+this.codigo;

            return s;
        }

}
```

Asignatura:

```
public class Asignatura {
    //VARIABLES
    String codigo; 
    String nombre;
    int horasSemanales; 
    String aula;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Asignatura(String codigo, String nombre, int horasSemanales, String aula){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.horasSemanales = horasSemanales;
        this.aula = aula;
    }

    //GETs
    public String getNombreAsignatura(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getCodigoAsignatura(){
        return this.codigo;
    }

    public int getHorasSemanales(){
        return this.horasSemanales;
    }

    public String getAula(){
        return this.aula;
    }

    //SETs
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setCodigoCurso(String codigo){
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    //OPERACIONES

    //toString
    public String toString(){
        String s="";

        s+= "El nombre del CURSO es: "+this.nombre;
        s+= "y el codigo es: "+this.codigo;

        return s;
    }

}
```

Alumno1:

```
public class Alumno1 extends Persona implements Alumno {
    //VARIABLES
    Asignatura[] asignaturas;
    int contAsignaturas3;
    Curso[] curso;
    int contCursos;

    //CONSTRUCTORES
        public Alumno1(String nombre, String dni){
            super(nombre,dni);
            this.contAsignaturas3 = 0;
            this.contCursos = 0;
        }

    //SETs
        public void setNombre(String nombre){
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public void setDni(String dni){
            this.dni = dni;
        }

    //GETs

    //OPERACIONES
        public String verAsignaturas() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public double verNotaAsignatura(String codigoAsignatura) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public String verInforme() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void asignarAlumno(Curso C) {

            this.curso[this.contCursos] = C;

            this.contCursos++;

        }

    //toString

        public String toString(){
            String s="";

            s+= "El nombre del Alumno es: "+this.nombre;
            s+= " y su DNI es "+this.dni;

            return s;
        }   
}
```

Profesor:

```
public class Profesor1 extends Persona implements Profesor {
    //VARIABLES
    Asignatura[] asignaturas;
    int contAsignaturas2;
    //CONSTRUCTORES
        public Profesor1(String nombre, String dni){
            super(nombre,dni);

            this.contAsignaturas2 = 0;
        }

    //SETs
        public void setNombre(String nombre){
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public void setDni(String dni){
            this.dni = dni;
        }

    //GETs

    //OPERACIONES
        public void ponerNota(String codigoAsignatura, String dni, double nota) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public String verAsignaturas() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public int verHoras() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public void asignarProfesor(Asignatura B) {

            this.asignaturas[this.contAsignaturas2] = B;

            this.contAsignaturas2 ++;

        }


    //toString

        public String toString(){
            String s="";

            s+= "El nombre del Profesor es: "+this.nombre;
            s+= " y su DNI es "+this.dni;

            return s;
        }
}
```

Interface:

Instituto:

```
public interface Instituto {
    /**
     * Crea un profesor para el instituto
     * @param nombre Nombre del profesor
     * @param dni DNI del profesor
     */
    public void crearProfesor(String nombre, String dni);

    /**
     * Crea un alumno para el instituto
     * @param nombre Nombre del alumno
     * @param dni DNI del alumno
     */
    public void crearAlumno(String nombre, String dni);

    /**
     * Crea un curso
     * @param codigo Codigo del curso
     * @param nombre Nombre del curso
     */
    public void crearCurso(String codigo, String nombre);

    /**
     * Crea una asignatura.
     * @param codigo Codigo de la asignatura.
     * @param nombre Nombre de la asignatura.
     * @param horasSemanales Numero de horas de la asignatura a la semana.
     * @param aula Nombre del aula donde se imparte la asignatura.
     */
    public void crearAsignatura(String codigo, String nombre, int horasSemanales, String aula);

    /**
     * Accede al profesor con el dni especifico
     * @param dni DNI del profesor a buscar
     * @return Objeto tipo Profesor
     */
    public Profesor getProfesor(String dni);

    /**
     * Accede al alumno con el dni especifico
     * @param dni DNI del alumno a buscar
     * @return Objeto tipo Alumno
     */
    public Alumno getAlumno(String dni);

    /**
     * Asigna una asignatura a un curso
     * @param codigoCurso Codigo del curso donde se asignarï¿½ la asignatura.
     * @param codigoAsignatura Codigo de la asignatura que se asignarï¿½ al curso.
     */
    public void asignarAsignatura(String codigoCurso, String codigoAsignatura);

    /**
     * Asigna un profesor a una asignatura.
     * @param codigoAsignatura Codigo de la asignatura a la que se asignarï¿½ el profesor.
     * @param dni DNI del profesor que se asignarï¿½ a la asignatura.
     */
    public void asignarProfesor(String codigoAsignatura, String dni);

    /**
     * Asigna un alumno a un curso.
     * @param codigoCurso Codigo del curso donde se asignarï¿½ el alumno.
     * @param dni DNI del alumno que se asignarï¿½ al curso.
     */
    public void asignarAlumno(String codigoCurso, String dni);

    /**
     * Pedimos una asignatura y nos da el informe con: 
     *      - Numero de estudiantes matriculados,
     *      - Numero de estudiantes evaluados (con nota introducida)
     *      - Numero y porcentaje de estudiantes aprobados (respecto a los evaluados)
     *      - Numero y porcentaje de estudiantes suspendidos (respecto a los evaluados)
     *      - Nota media de la asignatura (respecto a los evaluados)
     * @param codigoAsignatura Codigo de la asignatura a estudiar.
     * @return String con el informe de la asignatura.
     */
    public String informeAsignatura(String codigoAsignatura);

    /**
     * Muestra en que aula se da una asignatura
     * @param codigoAsignatura Codigo de la asignatura a estudiar.
     * @return String con el aula de la asignatura.
     */
    public String verAula(String codigoAsignatura);

    /**
     * Muestra que asignaturas se dan en un aula
     * @param aula Nombre del aula
     * @return String con la lista de asignaturas que se dan en ese aula.
     */
    public String verAulaAsignatura(String aula);

    /**
     * Muestra que alumnos est‡n matriculados en un curso
     * @param codigoCurso Codigo del curso a estudiar
     * @return String con la lista de alumnos que cursan ese curso.
     */
    public String verAlumnosCurso(String codigoCurso);
}
```

Profesor:

```
public interface Profesor {
    /**
     * Coloca una nota a un alumnos en una asignatura que el profesor imparte
     * @param codigoAsignatura Codigo de la asignatura a evaluar.
     * @param dni DNI del alumno a evaluar.
     * @param nota Double con la nota del alumno en la asignatura.
     */
    public void ponerNota(String codigoAsignatura, String dni, double nota);
    /**
     * Muestra el nombre y el aula de las asignaturas asignadas a un profesor.
     * @return String con la lista de parejas de asignatura-aula
     */
    public String verAsignaturas();


    /**
     * Muestra el numero de horas que da el profesor a la semana. Es la suma de todas las asignaturas.
     * @return Numero total de horas semanales asignadas al profesor.
     */
    public int verHoras();

    /**
     * GET DNI del Profesor.
     * @return DNI del Profesor.
     */
    public String getDni();

    public String getNombre();


}
```

Alumno:

```
public interface Alumno {

    /**
     * Muestra el nombre de las asignaturas matriculadas por el alumno.
     * @return String con la lista de asignaturas.
     */
    public String verAsignaturas();

    /**
     * Muestra la nota de un alumno para una asignatura.
     * @param codigoAsignatura String con el codigo de la asignatura.
     * @return Nota asignada al alumno en la asignatura.
     */
    public double verNotaAsignatura(String codigoAsignatura);

    /**
     * Muestra la informacion de un alumno:
     *      - Asignaturas matriculadas
     *      - Nota de cada asignatura (NP - en las no evaluadas)
     *      - Si esta todo evaluado y aprobado : 
     *              - Nota media de todas las asignaturas
     *      - Si no esta todo aprobado o evaluado : 
     *              - Lista de asignaturas a repetir 
     * @return String con la informaciï¿½n del alumno.
     */
    public String verInforme();

    /**
     * GET DNI del Alumno.
     * @return DNI del Alumno.
     */
    public String getDni();

    public String getNombre();

}
```

Clase Alumno:

```
public class Persona {
    //VARIABLES
    String nombre;
    String dni;

    //CONSTRUCTORES
    public Persona(String nombre, String dni){
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.dni = dni;
        }

    //SETs
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni){
        this.dni = dni;
    }


    //GETs
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getDni(){
        return this.dni;
    }

    //Operaciones

    //toString  
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Añade la interfaz Instituto y las clases Alumno y profesor por favor. Voy a probarlo

Comment: Ya esta actualizado, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si tienes algo como esto `public class Alumno1 extends Persona implements Alumno ...` debe de haber en algún lado una interfaz llamada Alumno y una clase llamada Persona. Tienes que ponerla. Lo mismo para `Instituto1 implements Instituto`.

Comment: Actualizado, lo siento soy nuevo en esto y no se muy bien como va.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en este `while`:

```
public void asignarAsignatura(String codigoCurso, String codigoAsignatura) {

        int i = 0;  
        int j = 0;

        while(this.curso[i].getCodigoCurso().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoCurso)){                
            i ++;
        }
```

Sólo tienes un objeto `curso` dentro de un array de 10 posiciones (el resto son nulas), en la primera iteración funciona sin problemas pero en la segunda intenta hacer el `getCodigoCurso()` de un objeto nulo (`curso[1]`) y de ahí la `NullPointerException`

Tendrás que hacer un tratamiento previo para evitarla.

Edito tras tu comentario:

Lo que tendrías que hacer entonces es buscar primero si existe el código de asignatura y en qué posición del array está y lo mismo con el curso:

```
public void asignarAsignatura(String codigoCurso, String codigoAsignatura) {

        int idxAsignatura=-1;
        int idxCurso=-1;

    // Buscamos si existe la asignatura a asignar
        for (int i = 0; i < this.asignatura.length; i++) {
            if(this.asignatura[i]!=null)
            {
                if(this.asignatura[i].getCodigoAsignatura().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoAsignatura))
                {
                    idxAsignatura = i;
                }
            }
        }

        //Buscamos si existe el curso
        for (int j = 0; j < curso.length; j++) {
            if(this.curso[j]!=null)
            {
                if(this.curso[j].getCodigoCurso().equalsIgnoreCase(codigoCurso))
                {
                    idxCurso = j;
                }
            }
        }

        if(idxAsignatura!=-1 && idxCurso!=-1)
        {
            this.curso[idxCurso].asignarAsignatura(this.asignatura[idxAsignatura]);
        }


        System.out.print("Asignatura Asignada");        
    }
```

De todas formas, ya que tienes la clase `Asignatura` y la clase `Curso` creadas, lo mejor es que trabajes directamente con esos objetos y con listas. Sería algo así:

```
public void asignarAsignatura(Curso c, Asignatura a) {
//Si el curso c está contenido en la lista de cursos seguimos
        if(Arrays.asList(this.curso).contains(c))
        {
            //Si la asignatura también está contenida, la asignamos al curso
            if(Arrays.asList(this.asignatura).contains(a))
            {
                c.asignarAsignatura(a);
            }
        }
}
```

Evidentemente tendrías que cambiar más cosas pero fíjate cómo se simplifica el código.

Te animo a leer sobre listas porque se simplifica muchísimo el trabajo con estructuras de datos (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Siguiendo con la implementación que te he comentado, te faltaría inicializar el array `asignaturas` en la clase `Curso` (si no te dará otra NullPointerException)

```
public void asignarAsignatura(Asignatura a){

        this.asignaturas[this.contAsignaturas] = a;

        this.contAsignaturas ++;

    }
```

Le he asignado un valor estático de 10 posiciones y funciona.

`Asignatura[] asignaturas = new Asignatura[10];`

Comment: Lo que quiero conseguir con el while es conseguir en este caso es que el curso que yo introduzca sea igual a una que yo cree anteriormente.

En conclusion yo quiero introducir un codigoCurso y un codigoAsignatura y que esa asignatura este dentro de ese Curso.